# do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers - Vuetify snackbar

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a snackbar from Vuetify. It's in `default.vue` and the `vuex` store controls the `v-model`, `message` and `color`:

DefaultSnackBar.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-snackbar
      v-model="snackbarProperties.show"
      :color="snackbarProperties.color"
      timeout="7000"
      multi-line
    >
      {{ snackbarProperties.message }}

      <template v-slot:action="{ attrs }">
        <v-btn
          text
          v-bind="attrs"
          @click="hideSnackbar"
        >
          Close
        </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-snackbar>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  methods :{
    ...mapActions("Snackbar",["showSnackbar","hideSnackbar"]),
  },
  computed: {
      ...mapGetters("Snackbar",["snackbarProperties"])
  },
}
</script>
```

Snackbar.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    message: "",
    color: "",
    show: false,
});

export const getters = {
    snackbarProperties: state => {
      return state;
    },
  
  }

export const mutations = {
    showSnackbar: (state, payload) => {
        state.message = payload.message;
        state.color = payload.color;
        state.show = true;
    },
    hideSnackbar: (state) => {
        state.message = "";
        state.color = ""
        state.show = false;
    },
}

export const actions = {
    showSnackbar({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('showSnackbar', payload)
    },
    hideSnackbar({ commit }) {
        commit('hideSnackbar')
    }
}
```

When I call `showSnackbar({...})` the bar appears correctly with no errors, but when it disappears (timeout is reached) is get this error and everything crashes

> do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

I think it's because when the bar disappears the component changes the value of the `v-model` it's attached to but I'm not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer from this [vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-how-to-do-a-state-change-in-settimeout-callback/28576/3):

> Use an action with the setTimeout code in it. Then in the timeout
> commit the mutation. Mutations should be synchronous which is why
> using a timeout in them is throwing a warning.

I've updated `Snackbar.js` to suit:

```
export const state = () => ({
    message: "",
    color: "",
    show: false,
});

export const getters = {
    snackbarProperties: state => {
      return state;
    },
  
  }

export const mutations = {
    showSnackbar: (state, payload) => {
        state.message = payload.message;
        state.color = payload.color;
        state.show = true;


    },
    hideSnackbar: (state) => {
        state.message = "";
        state.color = ""
        state.show = false;
    },
}

export const actions = {
    showSnackbar({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('showSnackbar', payload)
        setTimeout(() => {
          commit('hideSnackbar')
        }, 500);
    },
    hideSnackbar({ commit }) {
        commit('hideSnackbar')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if you need showing multiple

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-snackbar
      v-for="(snackbar, index) in snackbars.snackbars.filter(
        (s) => s.isVisible
      )"
      :key="snackbar.text + Math.random()"
      v-model="snackbar.isVisible"
      :color="snackbar.color"
      :timeout="-1"
      :right="true"
      :top="true"
      :style="`top: ${index * 60}px`"
    >
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col md="11" sm="11">
          {{ snackbar.text }}
        </v-col>
        <v-col md="1" sm="1">
          <v-btn class="mx-2" icon  small @click="hideNotify(index)">
            <v-icon color="error"> mdi-close </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-snackbar>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({ snackbars: 'notification' }),
  },
  methods: {
    hideNotify(index) {
      this.$store.dispatch('notification/HIDE_NOTIFY_WITH_INDEX',index)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

> add this into the vuex as  notification.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  snackbars: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_SNACKBAR(state, snackbar) {
    state.snackbars = state.snackbars.concat(snackbar)
  },
  HIDE_NOTIFY_WITH_INDEX(state,index) {
    if (index in state.snackbars) {
      state.snackbars.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },
  HIDE_NOTIFY(state) {
    state.snackbars = []
  },
}

export const actions = {
  SET_SNACKBAR({ commit }, snackbar) {
    snackbar.isVisible = true
    snackbar.color = snackbar.color || 'dark'
    commit('SET_SNACKBAR', snackbar)

    setTimeout(() => {
      commit('HIDE_NOTIFY')
    }, 6000)
  },
  HIDE_NOTIFY_WITH_INDEX({ commit },index) {
    commit('HIDE_NOTIFY_WITH_INDEX',index)
  },
}
```